# Trouble Implementing Apply for Either in C#

Tags: c#, functional-programming, monads, either

I am working through [Functional Programming in C# by Enrico Buonanno](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-c-sharp)

How would I implementing Apply for the Either monad in C#?  I tried the follow which does not type check:

```
using System;
using Xunit;
using LaYumba.Functional;
using static LaYumba.Functional.F;

namespace ch8
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Ex1()
        {
            Func<int, int, int> add = (x, y) => x + y;

            var option = Some(add)
              .Apply(3)
              .Apply(2);

            Assert.Equal(Some(5), option);

            var either = Left(add)
              .Apply(3) // does not type check
              .Apply(2);

            Assert.Equal(Left(5), either);
        }
    }

    public static class Ext
    {
        public static Either<L, R> Apply<L, R>(
            this Either<L, Func<R, R>> source, Either<L, R> target)
          => source.Match(
              l => Left(l),
              f => target.Match<Either<L, R>>(
                  l => Left(l),
                  r => Right(f(r))
              ));
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
watch : Started
Build started, please wait...
UnitTest1.cs(22,16): error CS1061: 'Either.Left<Func<int, int, int>>' does not contain a definition for 'Apply' and no extension method 'Apply' accepting afirst argument of type 'Either.Left<Func<int, int, int>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/ch8/ch8/ch8.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(25,26): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'LaYumba.Functional.Either.Left<int>' to 'string' [/ch8/ch8/ch8.csproj]
UnitTest1.cs(25,35): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'LaYumba.Functional.Either<L, R>' to 'string' [/ch8/ch8/ch8.csproj]
watch : Exited with error code 1
watch : Waiting for a file to change before restarting dotnet...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the technical proofer for the book, so if there are any bugs in there, it's my fault :)  A lot of what's in the book is based on my library [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) and obviously functional programming technique in general.  There's a fully fledged `Either` implementation there if you need it.

However, for your example, you almost certainly (can't check at the moment, I'm on a train) should be using `Right(add)` rather than `Left(add)` as `Right` is the success route, and `Left` is the fail route.

And you should therefore be asserting that the result is equal to `Right(5)`

It's been a while since I've looked at the book, but I am assuming that `Left` returns `Either.Left<L>` which doesn't have the same API as the 'success' route.

If you cast `Left(add)` to `Either<L, R>` then you'd find that the library opens up.

The `Left` and `Right` constructor functions have to deal with the fact that `Either` needs two types.  So they're creating intermediate values of `Left<L>` or `Right<R>` before implicitly casting to `Either<L, R>` - this will often save you from having to write `Left<L, R>(l)` and `Right<L, R>`(r), but sometimes the types trip over themselves.

Anyway, when I have a debugger to hand I'll take a closer look